# Help, how do i gamemode 3 / kill all players / etc an entire team in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

im having trouble with some Minecraft commands,
im trying to  kill @a/gamemode 3 @a/etc. an entire team.
For example: Destroying team by destroying a certain block,
and then the all of the BLUE player's losse.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: You are asking about target selectors and wanting to know how to use their different arguments.  [Here is the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selectors) to explain it all.  `/kill @a[m=3]` uses the correct target selector for everyone who is gamemode 3 as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any command on a whole team using the following target selector: `@a[team=TEAMNAME]`. Notice that team name and team color are two different things. You need the name, not the color.

Comment: Man... THANKSSS !!!   D-Inventor  thank you so much.